# How to identify Thin server processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thin

When starting multiple thin servers running Rails 3, is there any way to tell them 
apart in the code?

For example, if I have a configuration like this:

```
port: 4000
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
servers: 2
```

Is there a way to tell whether the code is runnin on the process on port 4000 or 4001?

Answer (score 1):

you can start 2 servers separately

thin start -p 4000
thin start -p 4001

:D

Comment: That won't help me doing anything like "if this_is_process_1 do this end". Although I could use the -r option to load code for only one of the servers, like `thin start -p 4000 -r code.rb; thin start -p 4001`.

Answer (score -1):

Supposing, that code, taht you posted is source of config/thin-config.yml

To start server with that parameters just do that:

```
thin start -C config/thin-config.yml
```

Yml files is the best way to configure server, but if you do not want to use them you can do that:

```
thin start -P tmp/pids/thin.pid -p 4000 -s 2
```